# ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations Validation ErrorMessageResourceType

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

When using Data Annotations Validation, everything works fine until I try to use resources.

Here's the error I get:
The name 'ErrorMessageResourceType' does not exist in the current context.

And the code I used:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.Web.Mvc;

namespace Project.Models  
{  
    [MetadataType(typeof(LanguageMetaData))]
    public partial class Language
    {
    }

    public class LanguageMetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType(typeof(Resources.Errors)), 
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "IdRequired")]
        public object Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType(typeof(Resources.Errors)), 
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "NameRequired")]
        public object Name { get; set; }

        public object Flag { get; set; }
        public object IsDefault { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can't find anything wrong with this. Can someone more experienced help me with what's wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It has to be

```
ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Errors)
```

instead of

```
ErrorMessageResourceType(typeof(Resources.Errors))
```

This was a small big damn stupid mistake :D

Hope this helps anyone who had the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both `ErrorMessageResourceType` and `ErrorMessageResourceName`.

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource),ErrorMessageResourceName = "Message_ValidEmail")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using nameof instead of string is a better option with *ErrorMessageResourceName* .

This is an example:

```
[StringLength(maximumLength: 60, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Register), ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Resources.Register.ChooseRole))]
```